How to overwrite Contao4 errorPage
I was trying to follow these steps but did not work:

Navigate to the templates directory.
Create a new directory structure that mirrors the original template path: 
templates/ContaoCore/Error/error.html.twig 
But this does not overwrite the original contao error page. Is there any help?


The correct path is
templates/bundles/ContaoCoreBundle/Error/error.html.twig

See https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/bundles/override.html#templates
